# When does a ring extension of a coordinate ring come from an open affine subset?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic set over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $\phi: k[X] \to R$ be a morphism of $k$-algebras. One can ask if there exists an open affine subvariety $U \subseteq X$ such that the the morphism $i^*: k[X] \hookrightarrow k[U]$ (induced by the inclusion $i: U \hookrightarrow X$) makes $k[U]$ isomorphic to $R$ as a $k[V]$-algebra. Is there a (relatively nice) algebraic condition on the map $\phi: k[X] \to R$ which determines when this is the case?

---

Note for example that $k[X],k[U]$ are finitely generated algebras over $k$, so $k[U]$ is always finitely generated over $k[X]$, which gives a neccesay condition on $\phi$.

Similarly, if $X$ is irreducible then we have
$$k[U] = \{f/g: V(g)\cap U = \emptyset\} $$
which is the localisation of $k[X]$ at the set $S=\{g \in k[U]: V(g)\cap U = \emptyset\}$, so we know that $k[X] \to k[U]$ must be a localisation. However, it can't be any localisation because for instance $k(X) \cong \textrm{Frac}(k[X])$ is not finitely generated over $k[X]$.

Comment: Quotient by a minimal prime ideal then invert finitely many elements?

Comment: @reuns If I'm not mistaken, inverting a finite set $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ is the same as inverting their product $f:=f_1...f_n$. But the localisation $k[X]_f$ corresponds to the subvariety $X\setminus V(f)$, and I'm not sure if every open affine subset of $X$ is of this form (or of this form where $X$ is replaced by one of its irreducible components)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20782/ring-theoretic-characterization-of-open-affines